# child component property not being updated when mounted()

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I have the following markup in a parent component

```
....
<div class="container-fluid">
          <claims :userID="userId"></claims>
          <claimForm :claimID="claimId" v-if="isDistributor"></claimForm>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
          <display :claimID="claimId"></display>

 ...........
 data(){ return { claimId: null } },
 beforeMount(){
        this.userId = this.isDistributor? this.currentUser.id: null

        this.eventEmitter.$on('claim.details', function(id) {
          this.claimId = id
        })
      }
```

Then in the child component known as `<display>`

```
, watch: {
      .....
      claimID: function(n) {
        console.log('claim');
        if(n == null) return false

        this.getClaimById()
      }
    .....
```

when an event bus `this.eventEmitter.$emit()` is emitted the parent component data `claimdId` is updated however the child component's `claimID` property doesn't seem to be updated thus the "watch" is not triggered.

What would cause the property to not be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case):

> HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so when using non-string templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:

so your code should be:

```
<claimForm :claim-iD="claimId" v-if="isDistributor"></claimForm>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight but when I also did this it STILL did not work however using an actual value `<.... claimID="18" v-if....>` works for some reason